# setup.py python module installation

Tags: python

i have the following

```
    Directory: C:\TWS API\source\pythonclient


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        3/17/2018   9:38 PM                ibapi
d-----        3/17/2018   9:38 PM                tests
-a----       12/28/2017   5:34 PM             98 .gitignore
-a----       12/28/2017   5:34 PM             37 MANIFEST.in
-a----       12/28/2017   5:34 PM           3269 README.md
-a----       12/28/2017   5:34 PM            526 setup.py
-a----       12/28/2017   5:34 PM             87 tox.ini
```

and want to install the module ibapi.

what am i doing wrong here?

```
PS C:\TWS API\source\pythonclient> python setup.py install

python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python setup.py install
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Please show the error message.

Comment: edited to include error message

Answer (score 1):

Note the error:

> python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

its likely that python executable not set in the environment variable, set it in your environment variable or navigate to directory where python installed.

[How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

try:
`python3 setup.py install

I have both python 2 and 3 installed on my system, so I had to specify.